# NULL usage in WHERE IN SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-in

I have below query

```
Select 
RPAD(x.QUOTE_ID,20,' ')
from csa_sli_all.T_CONV_XREF_CUST_QUOTE x ,
        csa_sli_all.T_CONV_quote q
where   q.select_indicator is null and 
    q.QUOTE_ID = X.QUOTE_ID and 
    q.HOLD_CODE IN ('CAQ' , NULL )
```

it doesnt give me required result.

I changed last statement to

```
where   q.select_indicator is null and 
    q.QUOTE_ID = X.QUOTE_ID and 
    (q.HOLD_CODE = 'CAQ' or q.hold_code is null)
```

Now its giving me desired result. My question is

1 can't we use `NULL` in `WHERE IN` clause ?

2 If yes HOW

3 Going by the logic ( not syntax : I know 1st syntax is wrong ) both scenarios will give same answers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set ANSI_NULLS OFF first, you can use IN (Null) Fine.

Comparisons to NULL can't be performed (=, >, < etc) with ANSI_NULLS ON

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
Select 
RPAD(x.QUOTE_ID,20,' ')
from csa_sli_all.T_CONV_XREF_CUST_QUOTE x ,
        csa_sli_all.T_CONV_quote q
where   q.select_indicator is null and 
    q.QUOTE_ID = X.QUOTE_ID and 
    q.HOLD_CODE IN ('CAQ' , NULL )
```

Should work fine

Comment: Ok, that sounds like something I would highly discourage anyone from doing. Ignoring the standard just for the sake of being able to compare `NULL`s? This could lead to big confusions while developing, maintaining and deploying your application.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use null values in a where clause using IN, so if you need to use it, use it like this:

```
q.HOLD_CODE in ('CAQ', ...) or q.hold_code is null
```

If you are looking for an null value you always have to use "is null" hence you can't use it in the IN statement

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `NULL` in `IN` statements, because `IN` applies the standard `=` operator. This one, of course, fails when comparing `NULL`s.

It's like writing `SELECT NULL = NULL`. Returned value would be `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but I dont think you can use NULL in where clause.

I always get confused with =NULL and IS NULL

why dont you use ISNULL ie ...

```
 WHERE ISNULL(q.HOD_CODE,'CAQ') = 'CAQ'
```

Answer (score 2):

`NULL IN (NULL)` evaluates to UNKNOWN. To compare null values you should use `is null` operator. Null has an specific treatment.

[Sample](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67234):

```
select case when null in (null) then 1 else 0 end

returns 0
```

[Remember Codd rule 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules):

> **Rule 3:** Systematic treatment of null values: The DBMS must allow each field to remain null (or empty). Specifically, it must support a
> representation of "missing information and inapplicable information"
> that is systematic, distinct from all regular values (for example,
> "distinct from zero or any other number", in the case of numeric
> values), and independent of data type. **It is also implied that such
> representations must be manipulated by the DBMS in a systematic way.**

Comment: Remember nulls weren't in Codd's original relational model? And that he later rejected the rule you quote in favour of two kinds of null, a proposal which was almost universally rejected? See: Wikipedia [Null (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_null): "In The Relational Model for Database Management: Version 2, Codd suggested that the SQL implementation of Null was flawed and should be replaced by two distinct Null-type markers..."

Comment: @onedaywhen, oh! thanks about ilustrate post with this quote. I thing that at this time this codd sugestion is deserted: "...  Because of this additional complexity, the idea of multiple Null-type values has not gained widespread acceptance."

Comment: Bottom line: I don't think you can use Codd in defence of SQL nulls  because he rejected SQL nulls and everyone else rejected Codd's nulls!

Comment: @onedaywhen, what is for you the major author reference for Null concept in databases?

Comment: The major author would IMO be Chris Date. There is an interesting article by both Codd and Date, [Much Ado About Nothing](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/1706814.htm). If you are looking for a critique of nulls on SQL, consider this article by Hugh Darwen: [On the Nothing That's Wrong With Nulls](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/2928212.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `is null` instead `= null`.

While comparing a field to `NULL`, a SQL query should use the `IS` operator in place of the "=" operator. The reason is that if the `ANSI_NULLS` option is On for a connection, expressions being compared to a NULL value will not return a true or false value but rather they will return an unknown value. To make it simpler, if a table xxx has a column by name col1 that contains two NULL values then this query would result in fetching zero records:

```
Select * from xxx where col1 = NULL
```

Meanwhile, this query would result in fetching two records:

```
Select * from xxx where col1 IS NULL
```

However, if you set ANSI_NULLS off then both of these queries would return two records.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a subquery, you'll have to use a join. Say for argument's sake you're using SQL Server, do something like (obviously filling in your fields):

```
SELECT yourField, yourField2 
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
WHERE t1.field is null
AND (t1.code = 'CAQ' OR t1.code IS NULL)
```